# Get available storage from Google Docs

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm building a Java application that involves Google Docs API. I'm using the old API ([Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/#java)) because the new one is much more complicated, and I spent hours trying to make it work.

Anyway, I used the example attached to the API, and got it working, as  I can get the list of files, download/upload/delete a file.

How can I get the available storage (remaining space in the cloud storage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Drive API v2 includes the amount of total storage and available storage in the About feed: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about